Sipml 5 client connection
I have install dsiprouter with letsencrpt certificates, i am trying to connect to the webrtc interface on port 4443 using sipml client and i am getting this _tsip_transport_ws_onerror
what could be wrong with my configuration, please help.
__tsip_transport_ws_onerror
SIPml-api.js?svn=252:1 __tsip_transport_ws_onclose
SIPml-api.js?svn=252:1 ==stack event = failed_to_start
I don't know what to do.

Firewall? Not enough info for debug.
